# Help with numerical analysis proof

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $u$ be a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and define $\gamma=\frac{2}{||u||_2^2}$ and $Q=I-\gamma uu^T$.

Prove Q is a reflector satisfying

A) $ Qu=-u$

B) $Qv=v$ if $<u,v>=0$

My approach: I'm letting some $$\hat u=\frac{u}{||u||_2}$$ so that $||\hat u||=1$.

I don't know where this is getting me though I'm missing a few details to prove A and B. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Caught that just now. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Qu = u - \frac{2}{||u||_2^2}uu^Tu = u - \frac{2}{||u||_2^2}u||u||_2^2 = u-2u = -u$

$Qv = v-\gamma uu^Tv = v-\gamma u \langle u,v \rangle = v$, if $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$

and because by definition $||u||_2^2 = \langle u,u \rangle = u^Tu$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = \alpha u + v$, where $v \in \operatorname{sp} \{u\}^\bot$.
Then $Q x = (I-\gamma u u^T) (\alpha u + v) = \alpha (1-\gamma \|u\|^2)u + v = -\alpha u +v$.

Hence if $v=0$, $\alpha=1$, we have A), that is, $Q u = -u$, and if $\alpha = 0$, (and $v^Tu = 0$, of course) we have B), that is, $Qv = v$.